# Найти "дыру" в двумерном массиве

Tags: java, массивы

Всем привет, я столкнулась с одной задачей и затрудняюсь с написанием кода.Помогите пожалуйста.
Дано: Двумерный массив -->

```
                     0 1 0 1 1 0
                     1 0 1 1 0 0
                     0 0 0 1 0 1 
                     0 0 0 0 0 0
                     1 0 1 1 0 0 
                     0 1 0 1 1 1
```

Вход: определим что дыра k это когда в строке ее все нули ,а в столбце все 1-ки кроме самого k который равен 0.
Выход: существует ли такой k и если да вернуть его значение если нет вернуть -1.
Код должен пройти со сложностью O(n).
Метод: public static int isSink(int [][] mat)

я написала такой код,но мне сказали что он неверный:

```
public static int isSink(int[][] mat) {
    int n = mat[0].length;
    boolean[] check = new boolean[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        check[i] = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (check[i]) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (i != j)
                    check[j] = false;
                else {
                    check[i] = false;
                    break;
                }
                if (i == j)
                    continue;
                if (mat[j][i] == 1)
                    check[j] = false;
                else {
                    check[i] = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (check[i])
                return i;
        }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: В чём конкретно возникли затруднения?

Comment: А практически какие сложности?

Comment: Теоретически я знаю что надо пройти по диагонали если я наталкиваюсь на 0 надо проверить если вся строка это нули,если нет - продолжать дальше пока не столкнусь со строкой где все нули .После я ищу столбик где все 1 кроме k который является нулем в строке которого все нули.
Я затрудняюсь в написании кода, а тоесть в построении цикла...Да так чтоб код прошел со сложностью O(n)

Comment: @KateYaqoobov надо вычислить суммы элементов столбцов и строк. Пересечение строки сумма элементов которой будет равна `0` и столбеца сумма элементов которого будет равна `высота столбца - 1` и дадут индексы элемента `k`. Для этого будет один проход по всему массиву для вычисления сумм и дальше отдельно проход по вычисленным суммам. В итоге асимптотическая сложность будет O(n)

Comment: зачем вычислять сумму элементов?
Надо просто пройти по диагонали ,при каждом нахождении нуля проверять строку в которой он находится если там все 0, плюс ко всему надо найти столбик со всеми 1 кроме этого 0 при нахождении такого надо вывести его значение а тоесть k=0 , а если таков не имеется то вывести -1.Таков имеется 4-ый столбик 4-ая строка .Но я затрудняюсь в самом построение цыкла....for...if...

Comment: @KateYaqoobov затем, что мой вариант в разы проще в реализации, да и по скорости особо не проигрывает.

Comment: @Yuri Heiko а вы можете написать код вашего варианта пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1):

Данный метод работает только для квадратных матриц

```
public static int isSink(int[][] mat) {
    int rowSum = 0;
    int colSum = 0;
    int colHeight = mat[0].length;

    int iterrationCounter = 0;

    int rowIndex = -1;
    int colIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++) {
            // Находи суммы элементов строки(rowSum) и столбца(colSum)
            rowSum += mat[i][j];
            colSum += mat[j][i];
            iterrationCounter++;
        }


        // Ищем строку в которой все элементы равны 0
        // т.е. сумма элементов, такой строки, равна 0
        if (rowIndex == -1 && rowSum == 0) {
            rowIndex = i;
        } else {
            rowSum = 0;
        }

        // Ищем столбец в котором все элементы, за исключением k, равны 1
        // т.е. сумма элементов, такого столбца, равна (высота столбца - 1)
        if (colIndex == -1 && colSum == colHeight - 1) {
            colIndex = i;
        } else {
            colSum = 0;
        }
    }

    System.err.println(iterrationCounter);

    if (rowIndex != -1 && colIndex != -1) {
        System.out.println("The sink is found by row:" + rowIndex + " column:" + colIndex);
        return mat[rowIndex][colIndex];
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: обьясните мне пожалуйста более подробно как я прихожу к k методом вычисления суммы элементов столбцов и строк?

Comment: Куда уж подробней? Пересечение строки, сумма элементов которой будет равна 0, и столбца, сумма элементов которого будет равна `высота столбца - 1`, и дадут индексы элемента `k`

Comment: Добавил комментарии к примеру кода

Comment: тоесть вы суммируете элементы строки и также суммируете элементы столбца?сумма элементов строки должно получиться 0 ...
но вот это я не поняла:   
 " и столбеца сумма элементов которого будет равна высота столбца - 1"?

Comment: Читаем условие задачи: `а в столбце все 1-ки кроме самого k который равен 0.` - это значит, что если наша матрица 6х6, то в таком столбце будет 5-ть `1` и один `0` сумма пяти единиц будет равна `5`. Высота столбца равна `6`, т.е. если мы нашли строку в которой все `0` и нашли столбец в котором сумма равна `5`, то их пересечение даст нужный элемент. Так как фактически мы перебираем все элементы матрицы только один раз, а потом делаем проверки по суммам строк/столбцов, то сложность будет равна O(n)

Comment: мы же вычисляем сумму  строк отдельно и отдельно столбцов,получается мы проходим по каждому элементу два раза,и тогда сложность получается даже больше чем O(n^2).Нет?

Comment: Считается количество итераций цикла, а их будет ровно столько сколько элементов массива.

Comment: даже если мы проходим по элементам один раз
в массиве  nxn надо пройти по n строкам n-ое количество раз..nxn=n^2

Comment: Матрица `1000х1000 = 1 000 000` элементов, т.е. сложность должна быть  ~ `О(1 000 000)`. Первый цикл вместе с вложенным циклом сделают `1000х1000` итераций при подсчете сумм элементов по столбцам и строкам. Следующие циклы сделают максимум `1000+1000 = 2000` итераций, т.е. результирующая сложность будет `O(1 002 000)`. Это соотношение `(1 000 000 к 2000)` c количеством элементов будет снижаться и им можно пренебречь, т.е. в итоге сложность можно выразить как `O(n)`

Comment: я тему сложности начала изучать недавно,но из того что мне известно главную роль играет именно  n а насчет сумм ...даже если сравнивать миллиард к одному ,это ведь не имеет значение .

Можете написать к примеру формулу сложности к вашему коду?Может я уловлю тогда вашу мысль.Ведь O(n) это конечный вывод, но его мы берем с определенной формулы.
(к примеру 2n+2 и тд)

Comment: К сожалению, я не математик и не могу вывести точную формулу сложности. Переделал алгоритм, может так понятней будет. В данном случае сложность равна O(n) без каких-либо констант или доп.вычислений.

Comment: @KateYaqoobov помогло?

Comment: Ваш код это O(n2)  а не O(n):(

Comment: @KateYaqoobov тот кто Вам это сказал, мягко говоря не программист. O(n*n) это когда у вас массив из 10 элементов, а вы по нему 100 раз проходите. O(n) это когда массив 10 и итераций 10. Если хотите проверить мой код, то просто добавьте счетчик внутрь второго цикла и посмотрите сколько итераций будет сделано.

Comment: Я добавил такой счетчик в свой ответ. Можете проверить, что на массиве из 100 элементов `new int [10][10]` будет сделано ровно 100 итераций

Comment: тот кто мне это сказал программист с тремя образованиями работающий в Intel(мой преподователь)
Есть две for
первая проходит по столбцам вторая - по рядам,mat.length это и есть n, так как у нас
  for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++) {
это и есть  n*n=n^2

Comment: @KateYaqoobov Катя, тем не менее он не прав. И количество образований или работа в Intel это не исправит. Можете ему это смело передать.На счет сложности - можете создать вопрос на этом форуме с моим вариантом решения и спросить это `O(n)` или `O(n*n)` вот тогда все и выясните.P.S. для одномерного массива два вложенных цикла означают сложность `O(n*n)` для двумерного массива(который в Java фактически является массивом из массивов) два цикла значат `O(n)`,так как внешний цикл перебирает ваши массивы, а внутренний элементы в них.Задайте вопрос на форуме, Вам самой будет полезно в этом разобратьс

Comment: O(1000000) = O(1), Не нужно использовать о большое для конкретных расчётов. Ваш код действительно имеет сложность O(N), если размером задачи считать `N = n*n`. ( *Но что тогда будет означать задача N+1? Но это такое...* ). Однако, Вы таки опозорились, потому что данная задача имеет решение за O(n).

Comment: @vp_arth Какое громкое слово "опозорились" такое чувство как будто я снова в первом классе :D. Вы конечно молодец, что нашли более удачное решение для любых матриц, но где я "опозорился" я так и не понял.

Answer (score 0):

Предположим, что дыра существует, и попытаемся её найти.
Для этого пойдём из угла (0, 0) по следующему алгоритму:

```
if (A[i, j] == 0) i++; else j++;
```

Мы придём в точку `(N, j)`, т.е. если дыра существует - это определённо дыра k=j.

Теперь, мы можем проверить наличие дыры k за 2 прохода(строка k и столбец k).

Итого, ровно 2 прохода + 1 диагональ для любого размера задачи,
другими словами `O(4*N) = O(N)`

Демо на javascript:

```js
function check(matrix, k) {
  for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i) {
    if (matrix[k][i] !== 0) return false;
    if (i!==k && matrix[i][k] == 0) return false
  }
  return true;
}
function solve(matrix) {
  let N = matrix.length;
  let i = 0, j = 0;
  while (i < N && j < N) {
    if (matrix[i][j] == 0) j++;
    else i++;
  }
  if (i < N && check(matrix, i)) return i;
  else return -1;
}

console.log(solve([
  [0, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 0],
]));

console.log(solve([
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
]));

console.log(solve([
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], 
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
]));
```

Comment: Что будет, если дыра находится в последней строке, но благодаря предыдущим строкам код до нее просто не доберется?

Comment: @etki, код всегда доберётся до дыры, если она существует. в последней строке все нули, значит в последнем столбце, все кроме одного единицы - т.е. мы в любом случае дойдём либо до последней строки и уйдём до упора вправо по нулям, либо дойдём до столбца с единицами и спустимся в последнюю строку.

Comment: @etki, добавил демо на js, можете поиграться со сниппетом. Вы, вероятно забываете, что k для столбца и для строки - это k, по условию.

Comment: Не работает ваше решение, если дырка не на диагонали http://js.do/code/204065 (поменял только тестовые данные)

Comment: @Виктор, ваши тестовые данные не соответствуют исходному определению задачи. Решение работает, дыр нет.

Comment: Что по вашему такое "дыра k не на диагонали"?

Comment: да, не прав был, но все же вроде сломал ваш код =) посмотрите вроде ничего не упустил, но последний выдает -1 http://js.do/code/204065

Comment: Ещё раз, "дыра k это когда в строке ее все нули ,а в столбце все 1-ки кроме самого k который равен 0" - она должна быть на диагонали по определению.

Comment: Меня больше удивило, что остальные не -1 =) Нашёл ошибку - ранний выход из цикла при проверке.

Comment: хаха, ну нашел ошибку, пусть и не ту что искал =) Сейчас условие перечитал, и правда не правильно его понял. Думал дырка может быть в любом месте массива, а оказывается обязана быть на диагонали...